# React: set value with two last input numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Got a situation and I'm not sure how to tackle it. When writing numbers in this input, I want to see only two last inserted numbers, no matter how many numbers I type. Example:

```
Input = 5  Value = 5
Input = 59 Value = 59
Input = 597 Value = 97
Input = 5970 Value = 70
Input = 59701 Value = 01
```

And so on.

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
function handleChange(e) {
  setNumber(e.target.value);
}
return (
  <div>
    <input type="text" maxLength="2" value={number} onChange={handleChange} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: No decimals, int only.

Comment: You can start with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer to string

Then use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to cut the last 2 numbers

```
const result = Number(e.target.value.toString().slice(-2));
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const result = Number(e.target.value.toString().slice(-2));
    setNumber(result);
    console.log(result);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" value={number} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or a more complex way as below

Using [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
const x = e.target.value.toString().split('');
const y = [x.pop(), x.pop()].reverse();
const result = Number(y.join(''));
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const x = e.target.value.toString().split('');
    const y = [x.pop(), x.pop()].reverse();
    const result = Number(y.join(''));
    setNumber(result);
    console.log(result);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" value={number} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Once you take full control with the handler function bound to `onChange` and `value`, there is no need for `maxLength` `defaultValue` related props.

Comment: Alright, it works, I'll need to examine this code, because I haven't seen some of this stuff. Thank you very much.